# Removing ^M from JSON output

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm using `requests` to get output of REST API call, save output to 1.json, then from that json file extract description and JIRA key

```
import csv
import urllib2
import argparse
import json
from bson import json_util

#password = str(sys.argv[1])
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
params = (
    ('jql', 'project="Technology" AND summary~"workspace creation*" AND issuetype="Task" AND status!="DONE"'),
)
response = requests.get('https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search', headers=headers, params=params, auth=('user', 'Pass'))

with open('1.json', 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write(response.content)
if sys.version[0] == '2':
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')

datapath = '1.json'




data = json.load(open(datapath))
for issue in data['issues']:
  if len(issue['fields']['subtasks']) == 0 and 'description' in issue['fields']:
   custom_field = issue['fields']['description']
   print custom_field
   print issue['key']
```

Output.txt:

```
  User:someuser^M
    ^M
    First Name:some^M
    ^M
    Last Name:user
    TECH-1427
```

I need to get csv file from this output.txt in following format:

```
someuser,some,user,TECH-1427
```

I'm using this code

```
re.findall(r'\bUser:(\S+)\s+First Name:(\S+)\s+Last Name:(\S+)\s+(TECH-\d+)', data)
```

data is content of output.txt file

Now, this only works if i manually remove  `^M` from output.txt, so how to get rid of `^M` during parsing 1.JSON file so it's removed from output.txt ?

Tried replacing but same results

```
sys.stdout = open('out.txt','wt')


    with open ("output.txt", "r") as myfile:
      data=myfile.read()


    print data.replace('^M','')
```

Comment: try .replace maybe e.g "this is my Name ^M".replace("^M"," ") output :'this is my Name  '

Comment: @toheedNiaz, tried it already, same output

Comment: If you make a request for data in JSON format, then you don't need to parse response as `response.content`, try `response.json()` instead to get clean JSON data

Comment: It is weird because `^M` is normally a representation of `'\r'` which is explicitely included in the `\s` class of characters... Could you give an hexa dump of data: `print([ (" " + hex(ord(c))) for c in data])`?

Comment: `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing like the following:

```
somestring.replace('\r','')
```

where `somestring` contains your data string data that you downloaded

Comment: `sys.stdout = open('out.txt','wt')
with open ("output.txt", "r") as myfile:
  data=myfile.read()
print data.replace(r'\r','')` got the same

Comment: `User:someuser^M
    ^M
    First Name:some^M
    ^M
    Last Name:user
    TECH-1427` is the output ^M is still there

Comment: Updated the ans. use `'\r'`